# Проблема с прыжками изображения в Safari

Tags: css, safari

Есть такая проблема в сафари https://take.ms/nhdmP
На видео видно подергивания изображения при скроле.
Стили изображения:

```
background: url(../images/inhtml/cow.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
background-size: cover;
height: 200vh;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 13%,100% 0,100% 93%,0 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 13%,100% 0,100% 93%,0 100%);
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 2;
```

Что было испробовано:

```
transform: translateZ(0);

transform: translate3d(0,0,0);

position:fixed;
```

Первые два свойства помогали частично, изображения просто пропадали :)
Какие еще могут быть варианты победы над этим багом?